# How to remove labels of nodes or edges?

Tags: apache-age

If I create a node using the following Cypher statement

```
FROM cypher('age', $$
    CREATE (g:User {name: "AGE"})
$$) AS (n agtype);
```

Is there a query to remove the "User" label from the created node?

Comment: This is a feature not supported yet, but planned to be implemented. It's filed under these issues: [#361](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/361), [#717](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/717)

Answer (score 0):

Until what [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20970338/marco-souza) mentioned gets implemented. You can try the following workaround:

Add a new property called NewLabel:

```
    SELECT * FROM cypher('age', $$
    MATCH (g:User)
    SET g.NewLabel = "Person" RETURN g
    $$) as (n agtype);
```

Going forward, you can try to retrieve by adding following after MATCH clause:

```
    WHERE g.NewLabel = "Series" RETURN v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a label from a node in Apache AGE using the REMOVE statement:

```
FROM cypher('age', $$
    MATCH (n:User {name: "AGE"})
    REMOVE n:User
$$) AS (n agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the 'REMOVE' keyword in your cypher query by including the following lines of code in the cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:LabelYouWantToRemove)
REMOVE n:LabelYouWantToRemove
```

Here, 'MATCH' will be used to find the specific node and then 'REMOVE' will remove the specific node.

Answer (score -2):

The label can be removed from a node in a similar way as any other property can be. The syntax involves using REMOVE keyword.

For removing the label we can use the following syntax which uses REMOVE keyword:

```
FROM cypher('age', $$
MATCH(n:USER)
REMOVE(n:USER)
$$) AS (n agtype);
```